# Laravel DomPdf dont support UTF-8

Tags: php, laravel-4

i'm trying to use [dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/tree/0.4) in laravel 4.2, in that document for support utf-8 i must be set

in meta tag, but does not work correctly. for example after pass string such as latin character such as Hello World, this package can create currect PDF, but when i set Arabic or Persian character such as `سلام`. created pdf file is empty without any string. i think my code is correct and this package dont support correct utf8

My code is:

```
$pdf = App::make( 'dompdf' );
$pdf->loadHTML( '<html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/><title>PDF</title></head><body><h1>سلام</h1></body></html>' );

return $pdf->stream();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the TCPPDF
It is available at the link below:
[laravel-tcpdf](https://github.com/maxxscho/laravel-tcpdf)

Comment: yeah!! i'm trying to use TcPdf now. dompdf supported utf-8 is wrong and after googeling web nobody can export file as an utf-8 encoding